# Is there way to find where(which file) defined certain method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, cfndsl

I have a cfndsl file with the statement:

```
SSESpecification(SSEEnabled: true)
```

on the local machine I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        12: from /usr/local/bin/cfndsl:23:in `<main>'
        11: from /usr/local/bin/cfndsl:23:in `load'
        10: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cfndsl-0.16.9/bin/cfndsl:138:in `<top (required)>'
         9: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cfndsl-0.16.9/lib/cfndsl.rb:87:in `eval_file_with_extras'
         8: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cfndsl-0.16.9/lib/cfndsl.rb:87:in `eval'
         7: from /c/work/dfsi/infra/cfndsl/cadnsw.rb:5:in `eval_file_with_extras'
         6: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cfndsl-0.16.9/lib/cfndsl.rb:93:in `CloudFormation'
         5: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cfndsl-0.16.9/lib/cfndsl/jsonable.rb:204:in `declare'
         4: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cfndsl-0.16.9/lib/cfndsl/jsonable.rb:204:in `instance_eval'
         3: from /c/work/dfsi/infra/cfndsl/cadnsw.rb:420:in `block in eval_file_with_extras'
         2: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cfndsl-0.16.9/lib/cfndsl/orchestration_template.rb:104:in `block (3 levels) in create_resource_accessor'
         1: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/cfndsl-0.16.9/lib/cfndsl/orchestration_template.rb:104:in `instance_eval'
/c/work/dfsi/infra/cfndsl/cadnsw.rb:470:in `block (2 levels) in eval_file_with_extras': undefined method `SSESpecification' for #<CfnDsl::AWS::Types::AWS_DynamoDB_Table:0x00007fffd918d478>
```

But on the server it is running OK without errors.

I just want to find out on server which file defined the method `SSESpecification`.

How should I do that with irb?

Comment: What’s wrong with `grep -r SSESpecification */**/*.rb` btw?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin or even better: `grep -r "def SSESpecification" **/*.rb`

Comment: Btw this is often useful: `grep "def SSESpecification" $(gem contents cfndsl)`

Comment: @KimmoLehto Yeah, I usually start with `"def foo"` but it could be `def self.foo`, `define_method foo` etc, especially taking into account it’s invoked with `instance_eval` :)